# Hashcat with only CPU and not GPU

Tags: hashcat

Can I use hashcat with the only CPU and not a GPU? I found hashcat-legacy but it isn't stable as much as hashcat current.

Comment: What do you mean by "with the only CPU"?

Comment: I have a server which doesn't has a gpu so I need to use cpu

Comment: Ok, have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, after opencl driver to a suitable OS(Ubuntu 16.04 x64), It's working